# Can't package up my PyQt5 application in PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5, fbs

I am trying to use FBSENV to package my software however my code in my main.py gives me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbs_runtime'
```

my import statement is:

```
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext
```

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment of fbs before packaging ?

Comment: I ran these in this order(sorry for spacing): python -m venv fbsenv``````````

call fbsenv\scripts\activate.bat``````````

pip3 install fbs PyQt5 PyInstaller==3.4``````````

fbs startproject`````````

fbs run`````````

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `from fbs_runtime.application_context import ApplicationContext`

Know that fbs only supports Python versions 3.5 and 3.6.

```
python3 -m venv fbsenv                  // virtual environment creation
call fbsenv\scripts\activate.bat        // run it
pip3 install fbs PyQt5 PyInstaller==3.4 // install required libs

fbs startproject // starting an app
fbs run          // run it
```

Application context:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = ApplicationContext()
    w = MyCustomWindow()
    ctx.app.exec_()
```

Everything's described [here](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/packaging-and-distribution/packaging-pyqt5-apps-fbs/)